# Java replaceAll only finding part of string

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am attempting to parse through a file of Java code and change comments that contain a dev's name and it switch the format. An example of comments are:

```
//Code modified by James on 10/28/2014 for report enhancement Start --- C1
//Code modified by Steven on 10/28/2014 to show report enhancement Start --- C1
```

And what I would like them to become:

```
// Company Name report enhancement Start --- C1
// Company Name show report enhancement Start --- C1
```

The replaceAll line I made is as follows:

```
String temp = line.replaceAll("//.*([Jj]ames)|([Ss]teven).*(to|for)", "// Company Name");
```

But the result string that I get is:

```
//Code modified by // Company Name report enhancement End --- C57844
```

I could just change the replacement string to only have the Company Name, but I don't understand why the regular expression drops the "//Code modified by" at the begin when it is part of the matcher. Explanations on why this is happening and suggestions on what to change my regular expression would be appreciated.

Comment: Took me a second but I think it's because ".*" is greedy.  Look up reluctant modifiers for regex, it'll help you out.

Comment: Works for me. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parentheses around the dev's names.

The pipe (`|`) character is taking the left part `//.*([Jj]ames)` and *ORing* it with the right part `([Ss]teven).*(to|for)`. Eventually you end up with matching either of the parts.

To solve it, you can adapt the parentheses as follows:

```
String temp = line.replaceAll("//.*([Jj]ames|[Ss]teven).*(to|for)", "// Company Name");
```

This way the OR pipe will be restricted to match either `[Jj]ames` or `[Ss]teven`.

Comment: Thanks! Ran in to this with the to|for, totally missed it with the dev names.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think you need a [reluctant modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for this to work.

Try:

```
line.replaceAll("//.*?([Jj]ames)|([Ss]teven).*?(to|for)", "// Company Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String line = "//Code modified by James on 10/28/2014 for report enhancement Start --- C1";
    String temp = line.replaceAll("//.*([Jj]ames)|([Ss]teven).*(to|for)", "// Company Name");
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

and got output:// Company Name on 10/28/2014 for report enhancement Start --- C1
so your replace is correct.You must have something else wrong in your code.